# How to validate html5 document against given structure?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have html5 document and I want to check its structure against some my own definition (similiar to xml file and XML Schema). Is there a way to do that except of some ugly manual parsing? Since HTML5 is not XML-friendly (not all tags have to be closed etc.) , I can't use DTD/XML Schema (or RelaxNG which I don't know) to do that, right?

Are there any schema languages or maybe even validators (like Saxon engine...)? Javascript/jQuery implementation would be best.

Sample:
- Rule: all  must be inside  or  elements - not sure which "language" to use to describe it more formally...

- invalid file:

  <!doctype html>
  ...
  <div><a>Invalid Link position<a>...
- valid file:

  <!doctype html>
  ...
  <div><table><tr><td><a>Valid Link position<a>...

Comment: Have a look at http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @ladar Could you provide 3 code samples? One valid html5 sample, one invalid html5 sample, and an example of what you trying to validate against. If I understand your question correctly, their might be a way to do some validation using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question,

[Yet another question regarding the html5 dtd/schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055206/yet-another-question-regarding-the-html5-dtd-schema)

There is no schema for HTML5. A quick google search would bring up these validators,

1. http://html5.validator.nu/
2. http://validator.whatwg.org/

But these require your HTML5 document to be public.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I meant (I've already read this question). Let's say I have a custom schema definition, that says that very link <a> must in inside <td> element.  I want to check given html5 against this schema so it will give me "OK" if all links are inside td (like the XML file and XML Schema).

Comment: Ah.. i get it. This is purely a suggestion. Try running HTMLTidy http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ on your HTML5 document to make it a proper XML. Then if you have your schema you can validate it like any other XML. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Some web browsers will check your page for you, if you are concerned about compatability stick with XHTML until html 5 has been wisely accepted, or a strict doctype is available for it.

Comment: Thanks, but please read my comment above, I want to check custom structure against html5 document