# HTML5 content model visualization

Tags: html

In HTML5 each element belongs to zero or more [categories](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-categories). Each element has a [content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-content-model) defined by zero or more categories.

In SO there is a lot of questions like: Can I put element A inside element B.

My question is: How to effectively build a visual represention of the content model?

Is it possible to generate a graph from a subset of elements in a synthetic way understandable by HTML5 users?

--EDIT--

This the kind of graph I want to generate. The arrows means can-be-inside.
[image: Example of a content model graph]

In some case, they will be conditions on arrows.

*Conditions:
(1) Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.*

Comment: [This Venn diagram from the WHATWG doc](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#kinds-of-content) illustrates how the content models are related, i.e., if **Phrasing** is inside **Flow** then an element categorized as **Phrasing** content is also considered **Flow** content as well. That should be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

In [HTML5 Reference - The Syntax, Vocabulary and APIs of HTML5 - The elements (W3C **2010**)](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-elements), you've for each element a list of the categories it pertains to, which elements can contain it and its content model...

… and good luck with that! As a related example, here's a graph for [WAI-ARIA roles](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles) and their aria-* something: **[graph](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/rdf_model.png)**. It's so complex and with tiny text... Other forms like a list or an autocomplete form giving information would be more useful I guess (but far more work and it doesn't go in a REC, sure).
I remember using, for HTML 4.01/XHTML 1.0, this french XHTML 1.1 clickable resource: [li](http://giminik.developpez.com/xhtml/li.html). It's in french but that's just an example of giving a title in blue with the name of the element, its intended use, (attributes blah) and below (too tiny) text with possible parents and children (*Liste des éléments enfants*) with red color being for elements that must have children (inaccessible coding relying on color btw).

Otherwise the excellent resource HTML5doctor has an index by alphabetical order: http://html5doctor.com/element-index/
On HTML5 validation, not SGML, DTD, schema, etc, good question, answers and links in this SO thread: [Yet another question regarding the html5 dtd/schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055206/yet-another-question-regarding-the-html5-dtd-schema)

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for a graphical way to represent the allowable content of an HTML element, I would suggest a set of **Syntax Diagrams** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram would be appropriate.   (Syntax Diagrams are sometimes called **Railroad Diagrams**.)

The JSON spec for example uses a set of syntax diagrams, and some believe the understandably of this format this has been helpful in its acceptance.  See [Tool for generating railroad diagram used on json.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796824/tool-for-generating-railroad-diagram-used-on-json-org) for some more detail about producing SVG diagrams programatically.

To illustrate, try pasting the following (incomplete EBNF) into https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui under the "Edit Grammar" tab and then click "View Diagram":

```
head-element ::= "<head" global-attribute* ">" metadata-content* "</head>"

metadata-content ::= title-element | base-element |  link-element | meta-element | style-element

title-element ::= "<title>" text-content "</title>"
base-element ::= "<base" (href-attribute | target-attribute | (href-attribute target-attribute)) ">"
```

A nice thing about this tool is you can feed it incomplete EBNF, and it will still diagram.

Comment: I'm not so interrested in the syntax but more in the "can-be-inside"-relationship between elements.

Comment: I'm thinking syntax and "can-be-inside" are near equivalent.  Would a <head> element be a good example?   Now the EBNF you use to generate appropriate diagrams wouldn't necessarily be the same as what you use to write a parser, but it depends on just how "strict" you want the diagrams to be.    I'll edit my answer and put a sample in.

Comment: OK, I think the example shows how this could be used.   There's lots you *might* choose to tweek,  e.g.
- Eliminate the global-attribute reference (to simplify)
- Make the </head> tag optional
- Show how the <head> tag can be omitted
Since we're not talking about using this EBNF to build a parser, just generate diagrams, its a matter of style.

Comment: According to this [article](http://trevorjim.com/a-grammar-for-html5/) the grammar of HTML5 is just `HTML5 = .*`. That's because HTML5 specification define how to parse errors. In my question, I'm interrested in the graph of the relation can-be-inside between HTML5 elements.

Comment: It's not a complete answer but I give you the bounty anyway.

Comment: Thank you sir.   I agree, technically HTML := .*, but as I trust you understand that's a truism. Since it's so broad and permissive, it won't help anyone to diagram that.   So a good diagram of the HTML tag would have to be authored to reflect some human's judgement of what "good" HTML looks like.